# I wrote a basic SQL Injection for my simple login php, but doesn't work

Tags: php, sql-injection

I'm trying to bypass my login code below

I try:

```
Username : ' or ''='
Password : ' or ''='
```

and

```
Username : ' or 1--
Password :
```

Following is the php:

```
 <?php
require_once('conn.php');

$empID      = $_POST['empID'];  
$password   = $_POST['password'];
$qry = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `sf_ohem_login` WHERE  empID='$empID' && password='$password'") ;
$num = mysql_num_rows($qry);
if($num==0)
{
    $data["login"]="false";
    $data["empID"]= $empID;
    $data["msg"]="Login failed due to wrong credentials";
}
else
{   
        $data["login"]="true";
        $data["empID"]= $empID;
        $data["password"]= $password;
}
echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by it doesn't work? What debugging have you done so far?

Comment: Did you try to dump the query with `echo` before executing it to see what your input actually does with it?

Comment: The SQL works fine, retrieves the correct user's data from the database. I edited the question as to what I mean by it doesn't work.

Comment: did you try `' or 1='1`?

Comment: What are you trying to do? What exactly does not work? You don't even ask a detailed question. What would you expect to happen when the injection works?

Answer (score -4, accepted):

This input did the work:

```
 empID= coo'or'1'='1
 password= coo'or'1'='1
```

Comment: So you're trying to inject something and as you say "it does the work". Ok, so what's your problem then? You need to be a bit more thorough in explaining what you want if you want to get meaningful answers...

Comment: I'm really sorry I was a bit naive with the question and the answer. Haven't asked too many questions here. 
I just wanted to Bypass my login page. Had to test if it was prone to SQL Injections. This code was implemented in my Android app, where users have to login. So an Injection would provide them full access.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
1' or 1=1 --+
```

After injecting this query, your PHP code will work like this:

```
empID='1' or 1=1 --+
```

Comment: What does the `+` after `--` do?

Comment: @SamuelShifterovich For string-based SQLi instead of Union/integer-based.